# I started training an object detection AI and my loss value is 22 digits long, how normal is this?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I downloaded my dataset from googles Open Image Dataset V6 and converted the txt annotations into VOC annotations so I could use it in Tensorflow following [this tutorial](https://mlhorizons.medium.com/preparing-open-images-dataset-for-tensorflow-object-detection-c3da6e688eb5).
I have 4 classes with a 100 training sets and 50 test sets each.I'm using google colab following [this tutorial series](https://youtu.be/f2ccs2xziLk).

As Im writing this, training is currently at step 26k and my loss value is now 23 digits long and I suspect its going even higher. I'm fairly new here but I'm pretty sure that number is suppose to be going down. I'd really appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

ok, so it wasn't suppose to do that... but I fixed it. I started snooping [here](https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fvijendra1125%2FCustom-Mask-RCNN-Using-Tensorfow-Object-Detection-API%2Fissues%2F25&h=AT25VdwVUStwM-bgdQbrWGOwZYPKbhShh_pQAA6UIP30ZHumqgLae4-lpYA3o60NTb1JJj_xizph0Is5EuC42Yj1h9Yu8XqS89Oj9jDnbxvPGcxE2hR5PrMuebyho6ydIcj_zOlEdoOwpyP_VKJi9tXqkk8) and eventually ended up [here](https://parthlathiya.medium.com/loss-explosion-while-training-a-custom-model-ad15fbc00d1). They call it 'Loss explosion'. Apparently in my case, my class names in label.pbtxt didn't match those in my tfrecord file when training.

Turns out that labels are case sensitive. I had the OIDV4 dataset already converted to VOC at this point but I still had the txt annotations hanging around. Checking the label text annotations from the downloaded dataset, I found out that they were labeled with class names with the first character in uppercase, way different from the class names I set inside my labelmap.pbtxt.

sO I wEnt ThrOuGH aLL 700 LABeL aNnoTatIon tXT fILEs BY HAND anD cHanGe-(no, not really, but I think you know what to do at this point :))

so...

HEED MY WARNING TRAINER!!!

check thine class names...

check thine labelmaps.pbtxt...

check thine generate_tfrecords.py...

check thine downloaded datasets...

else thine loss is by explosion...

or idk... just check your spelling I guess?